# Manipulate Push Notifications before showing (APNS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Good Morning!

I have a simple question: Can I manipulate the UIUserNotificationType.alert message before there is showing the client?

For example can I add a "1: " at the index 0 of the message?

That's just an example, I want to decrypt a message before I show them the client. Is there any way to do this like in android?

Until now I have only this snippet - but that only register the Notifications as types, I cant change the alert message:

```
let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible using APNS

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to Manipulate Push Notifications because it is handle by apple. You can also show apple official [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9/)

If you want to modify Push Notifications then you have No choice. You have to implement Apple Push Kit.

1) [Apple push Kit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/pushkit)

The Push Kit framework provides the classes for your iOS apps to receive pushes from remote servers. Pushes can be of one of two types: standard and VoIP. Standard pushes can deliver notifications just as in previous versions of iOS. VoIP pushes provide additional functionality on top of the standard push that is needed to VoIP apps to perform on-demand processing of the push before displaying a notification to the user.

All well known VOIP App use Apple push Kit for notification such as Whats App, Skype, Facebook Messenger.

Comment: Thanks for your notes. I think I need to read something about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a notification service app extension to modify the payload of a remote notification before it is delivered to the user.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html